# Ruby on Rails: railscasts comment system: inserting username into comment database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railscasts

I was following RyanB's polymorphic association video which shows examples of implementing a comment system.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised?autoplay=true

I was wondering how do I add a username into the database of the person that is creating the new comment? This way I can display username in the view pages,

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too many ways to do it

### Solution 1

If you will using authentication for comment system you should add one model user for authentication (suggest to use [devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=devise))

> ```
> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>   attr_accessible :email, :password, :username
>   has_many :comments
> end
>
>
> class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
>  attr_accessible :content, :user_id
>  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
>  belongs_to :user
> end
> ```

and on controller (take from [repository of 154-polymorphic-association-revised](https://github.com/railscasts/154-polymorphic-association-revised/blob/master/blog-after/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb) )

> ```
> def create
>     @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params[:comment])
>     @comment.user_id = current_user.id
>     if @comment.save
>      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment created."
>     else
>      render :new
>     end
> end
> ```

### OR Solution 2

You just add one attribute to comment model (without authentication)

> ```
>    class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
>      attr_accessible :content, :username
>      belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
>    end
> ```

Comment: What does the @comment.user = current_user mean? I am using devise. Right now, I'm displaying comment content like this `<%= simple_format comment.content %>`, how do I add on so I can do something like `comment.username`? Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry, I mean like this `@comment.user_id = current_user.id`, That is automatically store `user_id` in column of comments. If you want display username (user attribute), you just calling username such as `<%= comment.user.username %>`

Comment: When I tried putting @comment.user_id I get a `undefined method `user_id=' for #<Comment:0x007faeeb687b70>` error?

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped me get to the right path, and I believe, your first syntax was correct, `@comment.user_id = current_user`